# how to append duplicate values from json array to another array? not remove from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This array (`catalog`) contains duplicate values. I need to append duplicate values to an array.

here duplicate entries check by category and by name.

```
var catalog = {
  products : [
      { category: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
      { category: 'fos', name: 'item' },
      { category: 'nyedva', name: 'blabla' },
      { category: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
  ]
};
var categories = [];

$.each(catalog.products, function(index, value) {
  if ($.inArray(value.category, categories) == -1) { 
    //do nothing
  } else {

    if ($.inArray(value.name, categories) == -1) {   
      //do nothing
    } else {
      //add duplicate values to array
      categories.push(value.name);    
    }
  }
});

console.log(categories);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthar/aL3a51jj/)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @johnigneel how to append duplicate entries to an array

Comment: by any chance, do you mean remove instead of append ?

Comment: @atinder yes   that's it

Comment: First thing what i get from your question is you are checking for equality of objects. that check the current object matches with the object present in categories array.... am i right?

Comment: You want array of unique categories or unique names?

Comment: @Kenny yes u r right

Comment: @Vishwanath nop.. :( i need duplicate objects only

Comment: for that purpose i would recommend you to use underscore.js. You can use _.isEqual(obj1, obj2) will solve your problem

Comment: @Kenny i'm pretty sure the structure never change

Comment: @PrasanthAR, can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Grundy my inputs are shows in the code and output
{"category":"fos","name":"retek"}
{"category":"fos","name":"retek"}
this means the duplicate values of category and name append to the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var catalog={
    products : [
        { category: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
        { category: 'fos', name: 'item' },
        { category: 'nyedva', name: 'blabla' },
        { category: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
    ]
};

var categories = [],
    duplicates = [];

$.each(catalog.products, function(index, obj) {
    var key = JSON.stringify(obj);
    if (categories[key] === undefined) {
        categories[key] = obj;
    } else {
        duplicates[key] = obj;
    }
});

duplicates = Object.keys(duplicates).map(function (key) {
    return duplicates[key]
});

console.log(categories);
console.log(duplicates);
console.log(duplicates.length);
console.log(duplicates[0]);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aL3a51jj/3/)

Comment: your answer shows unique entries from array. not duplicate values

Comment: console.log(duplicates.length); return zero ?

Comment: @PrasanthAR I've just sent you an approach on how to find the duplicates. You can see yourself which type is `duplicates` and find a way to convert it to an array. I've just edited my answer but I think you're a little bit rude to not investigate yourself further..

Comment: i know it's my problem. but i tried to change my attitude.. anyway thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aL3a51jj/4/)

```
var catalog={
    products : [
        { category: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
        { category: 'fos', name: 'item' },
        { category: 'nyedva', name: 'blabla' },
        { category: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
    ]
};
var categories = [],
    uniqueCategories = [];

for (var i=0 ; i< catalog.products.length; i++) {
    var currProduct = catalog.products[i];
    if (uniqueCategories.length){
        for(var j=0; j< uniqueCategories.length; j++) {
           if(currProduct.category === uniqueCategories[j].category && currProduct.name === uniqueCategories[j].name){
            categories.push(currProduct)
           }
       }
   } else {
    uniqueCategories.push(currProduct)
   }
}

console.log(categories);
```

Comment: there is a problem with your answer multiple duplicate values on array, that's  never find any way thnx for your answer and help

Answer (score 0):

not very sure what you need, but as far as i understand, try the following code.

```
var duplicates = catalog.products.filter(function(item){
  return catalog.products.some(function(i){
    return i.category == item.category;
  });
})
```

Comment: Like! for using filters. Just started to do the same.